# Center within navigation

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to figure out how to allow the absolute centered logo to be surrounded by my navigation links (3 on each side), and for the navigation to fall below the logo upon resize seen here: http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/. I apologize in advance if this is answered elsewhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code:

**LOGO CSS**

```
h1.logo {
    float: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1.logo a {
    background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 127px;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 181px;
}

.abs {
    position: absolute;
}
```

**NAVIGATION CSS**

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
}
#navigation ul li, #navigation ul li a {
    border: medium none !important;
    color: #3C3F40;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Fjord One',"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 42px 0 130px !important;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigation ul li:hover a, #navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #D9A13B;
}
#navigation ul li:hover li a {
    color: #D9A13B;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#navigation ul li.active a {
    color: #D9A13B;
}
#navigation ul.sub-menu {

}
#navigation ul.sub-menu li {
    border: medium none;
}
#navigation ul.sub-menu li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-bottom: medium none;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    min-width: 210px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 8px;
    position: static;
}
#navigation ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
    border-bottom: medium none;
}
```

**THE HTML:**

```
<header class="sixteen columns">



 <nav>

    <h1 class="logo abs">
    <a href="/">Bound By Design</a>
    </h1>

    <div id="navigation" class="row sixteen columns">
        <div class="menu-header">

            <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu sf-js-enabled">

                <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
               object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-40 active">
                <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-41">
                <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/category/tattoos/">Tattoos</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-42">
                <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/category/piercings/">Piercings</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60">
                <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/aftercare/">Aftercare</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-58">
                 <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/category/news/">News</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59">
                <a href="http://testsite.brentthelendesign.com/contact/">Contact</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for the menu / logo?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You cannot float/flow around an absolutely positioned element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
#navigation ul li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 213px!important;
}
```

to layout.css and it will take care of the logo issue.

Also:

```
#navigation ul li, #navigation ul li a { 15px 0 26px 0 !important; }
```

will to get rid of the gap between the navigation and the 'WELCOME'

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that's a bit less dependent on your logo and page width:

```
#menu-primary-menu {width: 100%}
#menu-primary-menu > li:nth-child(n+4) {float: right}
```

Note that you'd have to reverse the order of the 3 right-floated menu items as they're stacked right-to-left.